# Hardware minimum requerid?

Tags: hardware

Hardware minimum required for install elementary OS 5.0?

Can I install elementary OS Only 5.1 with Windows 10 installed on another partition?

Can an 8 year old hardware install elementary OS 5.1?

Answer (score 2):

The recommended spec :

- 4-bit processor
- 4 GB of RAM
- 15 GB of free hard drive space (SSD is better)

All informations here :

https://elementary.io/docs/installation#installation

Answer (score 1):

***Hardware minimum requerid for install Elementary OS 5.0?***

Your are all informations here : https://elementary.io/docs/installation#installation

***Can I install Elementary OS Only 5.1 with Windows 10 installed on another partition?***

Yes you can and you have the choice during the installation

- Install alongside Windows 10
- Somthing else if you want to do an advanced installation, such as
  installing on a different hard drive or partition

[image]

***Can an 8 year old hardware install Elementory SO 5.1?***

Yes you can try. I recommand you to do a test with a live USB CD